# how to set id attribute in a loop for div element in javascript. USING childnode or something else

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

```
<div id="demo" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
 <div id="show">
  <div>Srikanya : 4K,DolbyAtmos</div>
  <div id="showtimes">
   <div>11:00am</div>
   <div>02:00pm</div>
   <div>06:00pm</div>
   <div>09:30pm</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```
  const collection = document.getElementById("demo").children;
  for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    collection[i].id = "show";
    collection[i].lastChild.id = "showtimes";
    collection[i].lastChild.children.id = "timings";
```

**I want to set the id attribute  for the childnode of showtime in a loop but I was unable to do that i don't know what was a problem in my code  **

**I want to set the id attribute  for the childnode of showtime in a loop but I was unable to do that don't know what was a problem in my code on using js **

Comment: Welcome to SO. What are you expecting your output markup to look like. You should update your question with that.

Comment: i want to set the id attribute to the "show" ChildNodes in loop as id "timings"